# Databricks: how to find the source of mounted point?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

The following command returns a list of mounted point of Databricks:

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/")
```

Let's assume the "/mnt/point_name/" point exists.
How check to with source the point is connected? E.g. How to find a relation between Azure Storage Account and mount point?

I am bit confused why I can not find any information about mounted point in Azure Databricks in documentation and over the internet...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dbutils.fs.mounts()`
how looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information by running `dbutils.fs.mounts()` command (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-fs-mounts)) - it will return a list of the `MountInfo` objects, consisting of the `mountPoint` (path to mount point) and `source` (what object is mounted) fields